# Converge Lightbox Integration

Tags: payment-gateway

I am implementing Converge lightbox . Dev server IP has been whitelisted .I could get session token by consuming 
"https://api.demo.convergepay.com/hosted-payments/transaction_token"

However i am getting 403 error code on calling 
  PayWithConverge.open(paymentFields, callback)

Need help here

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function openLightbox() {
        var paymentFields = {
            ssl_txn_auth_token: document.getElementById("token").value
        };
        var callback = {
            onError: function (error) {
                showResult("error", error);
            },
            onCancelled: function () {
                showResult("cancelled", "");
            },
            onDeclined: function (response) {
                showResult("declined", JSON.stringify(response, null, '\t'));
            },
            onApproval: function (response) {
                showResult("approval", JSON.stringify(response, null, '\t'));
            }
        };
        PayWithConverge.open(paymentFields, callback);

    }
    function showResult(status, msg) {
        document.getElementById('txn_status').innerHTML = "<b>" + status + "</b>";
        document.getElementById('txn_response').innerHTML = msg;
    }


</script>
```

error:

api.demo.convergepay.com/hosted-payments/assets/hpm-1.1.34-3.js:5 POST https://api.demo.convergepay.com/hosted-payments/service/payment/hpm/initialize 403 (Forbidden)
(anonymous) @ api.demo.convergepay.com/hosted-payments/assets/hpm-1.1.34-3.js:5

Answer (score 4):

You need to have your domain listed as an Authorized Referrer in the [Converge Portal](https://www.convergepay.com/converge-webapp/#!/login) - Settings > System Setup - HTTP Options (even when  Use HTTP Referrers was unchecked). You would need to call support for adding it.

Also, it is only supposed to work from https websites.

Comment: If i add multiple domain names in Referrers , will it throw below error   https://api.demo.convergepay.com/hosted-payments/service/payment/hpm/initialize 500 (Internal Server Error) .  For me its showing the same

Comment: @GyanPrakashSatapathy I have experienced the same error. I called support, they removed and added the Referrers again and now it works for all the domains.

Comment: can I test it in localhost?